# Windows 10 Photos

Tags: photos

I've started setting up `Photos` to recognise people. Most of the time it gets them right but there are some where the wrong people are included in a person. How do I get rid of these interlopers?

Comment: You should be able to unselect Photos linked to a contact in the People tab.